# Iterated polyhedron face twisting

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

Let $Q$ be a polygon in the plane. Modify $Q$ by rotating each edge about its
midpoint by $180^\circ$. The result is $Q$ again: No change.

This suggests exploring a similar operation in $\mathbb{R}^3$
(somewhat analogous to the earlier questions,
[The limit of edge-midpoint convex polyhedra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/184836/6094)
,
and ["Derived" polyhedra and polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149770/6094)
.).

Let $P_0$ be a (closed) convex polyhedron. 
Modify $P_0$ by rotating each face about its centroid, about
the face normal, by $\theta=2\pi/3=120^\circ$. This produces a jumble of polygons
(triangles if $P_0$ has all faces triangles). Let $P_1$ be the convex hull of these twisted faces. Continue, producing $P_2, P_3, \ldots$.
For example:

---

[image: Sequence]

          

<sup>$P_0, P_1, P_2$, of $10, 21, 29$ vertices respectively.</sup>

---

With $\theta=2\pi/3$, the deltahedra (with equilateral triangles faces)
are fixed points. My question is:

> ***Q1***. Does the iteration "generally" tend to a smooth surface in the limit, perhaps even a sphere? If not, can any characteristics of the limit be identified?

Starting with quite non-spherical $P_0$ does seem to tend
toward "rounding out":

---

[image: P20]

          

<sup>Three random $10$-vertex $P_0$, and their corresponding $P_{20}$.</sup>

---

> ***Q2***. Are there any "fixed points" aside from the deltahedra,
>   i.e., some $P_0$ that eventually leads to $P_k$ that is similar
>   to $P_0$, congruent after scaling and rotation?

Comment: Trivially, the faces can also be regular $3k$-gons and still stay fixed under that rotation, so e.g. the [truncated tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_tetrahedron) (having only regular hexagons and equilateral triangles as faces) is also a "fixed point".

Comment: In addition there is the infinite sequence [hexagonal antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_antiprism), [enneagonal antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneagonal_antiprism), [dodecagonal antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagonal_antiprism), etc.; they are also non-deltahedra for which $P_1$ equals $P_0$ in the most trivial way.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Nice observations--Thanks!

Comment: You could use another $\theta$, like $\theta=\pi=180^\circ$. This time other polyhedra are "fixed points" in the most trivial way. You could also go back to the plane polygon where you rotate edges around their midpoints, and pick an "arbitrary" but fixed $\theta$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It would be especially interesting if there were fixed points in a non-trivial sense---reached after more than just 1 iteration.